# How to use fetch_style parameter with custom query in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I am trying to fetch assocaited data columns in Magento 2.

working code as below:

```
$tablename = $connection->getTableName('dummy_table');
$query = "SELECT title,identifier FROM $tablename ORDER BY title";
$resultLinks = $connection->fetchAll($query);
```

Now I am trying below but its not working

```
$tablename = $connection->getTableName('dummy_table');
$query = "SELECT title,identifier FROM $tablename ORDER BY title";
$resultLinks = $connection->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

How can we use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use slash before your arguments.

```
$tablename = $connection->getTableName('dummy_table');
$query = "SELECT title,identifier FROM $tablename ORDER BY title";
$resultLinks = $connection->query($query);
$resultLinks->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```